# Relation in database between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write database for maternity ward and I have no idea how to create relation that lets doctors be also patients.

Here is link for my databse script:
http://pastebin.com/Pm0nsBtJ

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a new column to `doctors` that references `patients(id_patient)`. It will point to Null if a doctor is not a patient.

Comment: maybe have a "people" table, and then another table for "roles" which lets you specify if the person is a doctor or patient or both. Or let the "patients" and "doctors" tables contain a foreign key to "people". Either way you only enter the personal data once, and you have a means to query whether a doctor is also a patient.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Foreign Key field to the Patients table that references an Employee ID and is not required. This way a patient could possibly be an employee and that employee could be a doctor or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can uniquely identify a patient by their PESEL number (Polish national identification number).

So if it really is necessary to know that patient Mateusz Bacik with PESEL no. 66062012395 is Dr. Mateusz Bacik, then simply add the PESEL number to the doctors table.